# get_adjacent_post() returning weird results

Tags: order, previous, next

I am using `get_adjacent_post()` function to display links to a previous and next post. It is a custom post which also has a custom taxonomy.

This is the code I am using:

```
$prev = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
$next = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);

if($prev){
    $url = get_permalink($prev->ID);            
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Previous</a>';
}

if($next) {
    $url = get_permalink($next->ID);            
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Next</a>';
}
```

As far as I understand, the parameters in the `get_adjecent_post()` function should consider all posts, since I am not restricting the selection to any taxonomy. However, it shows weird results. Currently I have 15 posts of this post type, the latest one only shows "previous" button (which is OK), but the second-latest only shows "next" button, as if there were only two posts. When I open another post manually I can go in both directions, but I am not able to go through all of the posts - **as if there were some groups of posts created**, and the `get_adjecent_post()` function only searches within these groups.

I am using Post Types Order plugin to customize the order of created posts and I think there could be some conflict.

Is something wrong in my code? Am I using the function in the wrong manner?

Comment: By default `get_adjacent_post` orders posts by post_date, so it should work just fine. But it allows to change that order using filters, so maybe PTO breaks it... Does it work when you disable PTO?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż yes, it is indeed a PTO issue. After deactivation it works great. Is there any native WP function that gets next and previous post that is not in conflict with PTO? (I know this is more of a PTO support forum question)